# dynamically inserted anchor tags are not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

I am appending anchor tag from jquery. While clicking on this anchor tag, does nothing. I triedd by changing anchor to div and added onclick event too. But it is not working.

Html:

```
    <li class="list">
        <div class="dropdown" data-load="true">
        <span class="dropdown-toggle"></span>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li>
                    <span class="list-name" href="javascript:void(0);">
                        test
                    </span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
```

Script:

```
    var element = $(".list").find("ul");
    var options = "";
    options += "<li><a class='list-name' href='www.test.com' target='_blank' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' data-original-title=''>" + "some value" + "</a></li>";
    element.html(options);
```

Output:

```
    <li class="list">
        <div class="dropdown" data-load="true">
        <span class="dropdown-toggle"></span>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li>
                    <a class="list-name" href="www.test.com" target='_blank' data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="">some value</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
```

Comment: You are missing the protocol. eg. `https://` or `http://`

Comment: What do you mean with "it's not working" what does not work? like if you put quotes around "some value" it does work: https://jsfiddle.net/yk154x7p/ doesn't it ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have double quotes around "some value". I have edited now.  Still anchor tag is not working.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/anubala/kpgfgt74/

```
 var options = "";

options = "<li><a class='list-name' href='www.test.com' target='_blank' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' data-original-title=''>" + "some value" + "</a></li>";
```

$(".list").find("ul").html(options);